# Hi, Can anyone tell me the method/calculation behind this <h1> tag height?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am new to html, css and I was going trying to making a small page to understand the css measurement units. I have this container class with a font-size of 30px so I thought everything inside this container  class parent will have a font-size of 30px unless you give an another font-size for a particular child inside this container class parent. Here the  tag has a height of 51.2. I thought it will be 30px from the container class. I think I am missing something or unclear about the method of measurement. Any Help would be appreciated. Ty.

**#html syntax**

```
<body>
 <section id="hero">
   <div class="hero container">
     <div>
       <h1>Hello, My Name is Bubba</h1>
       <a href="#" type="button" class="cta">Portfolio</a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>
</body>
```

**#css syntax**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(161, 155, 155);
}

.container {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLQcD.png)

Comment: `line-height`, maybe? But please include your code as text in the question.

Comment: Hi Akash, welcome to SO! When not set, all elements inherit the font size of `body` unless you use `em` as a font size unit for child elements. In that case they will inherit the size of their parent when set (in your case 30px). E.g. `.parent { font-size: 30px } .child { font-size: 1.5em }` means that the child font size will be 1.5 * 30 = 45px. Do some research on using `em/rem`. Remember `rem` = root/html font size dependent, `em` = parent font size dependent. Also check [w3schools h1-h6](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp) section 'Default CSS Settings'...

Comment: hi, @Ry- I have added the code in the question. I am new so I didn't know.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I understood this part. but here its taking extra height in addition also, Maybe line-height. Need to check

Answer (score 0):

Remember that browsers will add styling for certain elements.

In this case the browser is setting the font size of an h1 element within a section element to 1.5em. Which is 45px.

Remember also that a character's height is not the same as the font-size - as has been pointed out in the comments line height (and leading) comes into play.

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-tame-line-height-in-css/#:%7E:text=Leading%20is%20defined%20as%20the%20distance%20between%20two,the%20margin%20and%20padding%20from%20every%20single%20element.) discusses line height and leading.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the article link. Got a clear understanding now.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, there's is something going on in the background:

- The HTML default for a `h1` element is

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-block-start: 0.67em;
    margin-block-end: 0.67em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

After some testing in most recent Windows Firefox and Edge, it appears that in both browsers some `h1` default values get overridden with

```
:-webkit-any(article, aside, nav, section) h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-block-start: 0.83em;
    margin-block-end: 0.83em;
}
```

Why this code is inserted by the browsers (user agent CSS internal files) is unclear to me. Probably because it is the first `h1` inside the first `section`, as per some W3 Consortium specification.

- When a `line-height` for an element (or `<body>`) is not set the default line height will *roughly* be (that's right, **not** *exactly* [MDN 'line-height: Values'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#values) ) a value between `1.1` and `1.2` (or `110%` and `120%`, depending on browser).
- When using the `em` unit for any size value (as `h1` above does by default with `font-size`), the `font-size` of the direct parent will be used to calculate the child element font size.

In this case the final computed value for `h1 font-size: 30px * 1.5em = 45px` times *roughly* `110% or 120%` will yield a font size between `49.5px and 54px`.

Your computed `h1 font-size 51.2px` lies neatly within those two values. The final computed element height depends on `font-family` *leading space* as @AHaworth depicted.

I know, right? We developers hate 'sortof' calculations...

**To circumvent the vagueness above**, you might want to set a default line height for the entire document in CSS `body` as all elements inherit this value. Often values between `1.2` and `1.3` are used. For *a11y* (accessibility) a default line height of at least `1.5` is advised. I often use `20/16 = 1.25`.

**Be aware** that most font-families slightly differ in height because of font specific spacing. Therefore it is imperative to set a high enough default `body line-height` to fit the tallest font in your document. This way you have control over element heights in your CSS calculations as element heights (when not set in CSS) are **based on** `line-height` **not** `font-size`.

Comment: Didn't know about this topic. Thank you. I guess I need to browse more topics under html and css. So many concepts